# $setTouched and $setPristine not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am new to angularjs. I have a form that accepts information from the user.(information like name, address etc... ) I was able to show validation for each info but the problem is validation still exist even if I reset the form using `$setUnTouched` and `$setPristine`. What have gone wrong in my code. Thanks in advance

```
<div ng-controller="PersonController as pCtrl">
       <form name="personForm">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" ng-model="pCtrl.personForm.firstName " ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/"/>
           <div class="help-block" ng-messages="personForm.firstName.$error" ng-if="personForm.firstName.$touched">
              <p ng-message="">Your name is too short.</p>
              <p ng-message="pattern">Invalid. Input alphabetic characters</p>
              <p ng-message="required">First name is required.</p>
           </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="pCtrl.resetForm(personForm)" >Save</button>
       </form>
</div>
```

IN MY ANGULAR JS

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate','ng-slide-down', 'ngMessages']);
    app.controller('PersonController',function($scope, $http ) {
           var pCtrl = this;

          pCtrl.resetForm = function(form) {
                  form.$setPristine();
         }
    });
```

as you see I created a function named "resetForm" to set the form named" =

Comment: could you please, specify in more detail which is the desired behavior? For instance, would you like to reset the form in the "save" click no matter whether it's valid or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your form without using `$setPristine` (I reset forms often but never use that service, although I will look more into it).

An easy way to reset your form value is to set your `<input>`'s `ng-model` to a blank object or string, after form submission, and this will reset the form:

### Your Controller Function:

```
pCtrl.resetForm = function(form) {
    pCtrl.personForm.firstName = ''; 
    // this will set `.firstName` to be empty and clear the form value.
        /* 
            Note: this assumes the original value has been passed 
            to the server already and it's OK to reset this value 
        /*
}
```

Usually I setup a callback function that sends to my factory, and then to the server, which resets the form after. I'll share an example:

### Example HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="create()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <input type="submit" value="Create User">
</form>
```

When the `Create User` button above is clicked, `create()` will run in the controller (which ultimately funnels data to the factory, and then the factory talks to the sever and jockeys the response back to the angular controller).

You can see in my angular controller below, I've created a callbacks object that I use to pass along functions I want to run **after** data has been returned from the server. These functions run in my angular factory, which I'll also show after the controller.

### Example Angular Controller:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myFactory', function($scope, myFactory) {
    // Callbacks
    var cb = {
        create: function(message) {
            console.log(message);
            $scope.user = {}; // this resets my user object and any form fields after user is created
        },
    };

    // Create User:
    $scope.create = function() {
        console.log('Create Process: Angular controller running...', $scope.user);
        userFactory.create($scope.user, cb.create); // see how both '$scope.user' and the 'cb.create' callback function are passed to factory?
    };
}]);
```

### Example Angular Factory:

I've omitted the server controller, but you can see here in the factory below, that when `create` runs, it goes to the server, makes the new user, and then afterwards runs the callback from above, effectively resetting the user field. You'll see the parameters of my factory method allow for the callback argument from the Angular Controller to be passed:

```
app.factory('myFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
    // Setup Factory Object:
    var factory = {};

    // Create:
    factory.create = function(user, createCallback) { 
        $http.post('/user', user) // Note: server controller and `/user` route not shown
            .then(function(message) {
                createCallback(message.data); 
                // this runs the callback function in our controller,
                // which resets the `$scope.user` object to an empty string.
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err.data);
            })
    };

    // Return Factory Object:
    return factory;
}]);
```

I will scope out the `$setPristine` service, but this is the way I was taught to reset forms. Just change your model object to an empty array or string, and your form value will clear because of Angular's two-way data binding. It's pretty sweet.